# Filming a traffic infraction in the US can result in a traffic ticket for the offending driver?

Tags: legal, traffic

In the US can anyone film a traffic infraction, and submit for the police, and that can result in a traffic ticket for the offending driver?

Comment: I'd presume that depends entirely on what country the incident occurs in. Which country are we talking about?

Comment: I think this would be better asked on [law.se]. You should include which jurisdiction(s) you're referring to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a travel question.

Comment: This might be a travel question if you wanted to know whether your dashboard cam is legal in other countries, or what to do with the footage a passenger took of some dangerous driving in a country where you don't know the legal system. But as it stands it's too broad for any site and doesn't appear to have a travel connection.

Comment: In many jurisdictions and circumstances it may allow the police to start and investigation but not necessarily be enough to actually fine or prosecute the offender, as it may not meet the burden of proof: the picture or video may have been doctored. Often only such media taken by sworn officers and/or using certified equipment will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking here on Travel Stack Exchange, I guess you plan to do that in a country other than your own.

- Many countries have traffic regulations which prohibit drivers from playing with their phone while driving. Submitting the video as evidence would implicitly admit a traffic violation of your own.
- Some countries have privacy laws which limit making videos of other people without their consent. These laws can be complex and come with many exceptions. The safe thing is to *ask politely* before you make pictures where other people are recognizable.
  A permanently installed dashboard camera might violate these laws, not because it records a traffic violation but because it records the time before and after.